# What should be done If I need to create abstract class or interface instance using Java?

Tags: java, spring, interface, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm learning Java and Spring framework, so, in my Java web application I have interface `Client` and 2 classes that implements this interface - `PersonClient` and `CompanyClient`. Also, there is interface `Account` and class that implements this interface - `DebitAccount`:

```java
package com.bankapp.bankwebapplication.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class DebitAccount implements Account {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }

    private Long clientId;
    public Long getClientId() { return clientId; }
    public void setClientId(Long clientId) { this.clientId = clientId; }

    private Long amountOfMoney;
    public Long getAmountOfMoney() { return amountOfMoney; }
    public void setAmountOfMoney(Long amountOfMoney) { this.amountOfMoney = amountOfMoney; }

}
```

This class has filed `clientId`. And here is a problem. As you can see, this is not DB, so, I can't just create `private Long clientId`. It has to be class instead of `Long` data type, but, I have interface, and I can't create interface instance, but I understand, that I can't leave it this way, it has to be class data type, not `Long`.

I was thinking about abstract class, but, as same as interface, it's about polymorphism and I can't create abstract class instance either. How to figure that out? Or should I just create 2 fields for `CompanyClient` and `PersonalClient`?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. What's stopping your from declaring a `Client client;`?

Comment: First of all, as I know, you can't create instance of interface (in this case) of abstract class, and the second, when I try to do that, I get this error: `'Basic' attribute type should not be 'Client'`

Answer (score 1):

"...this is not DB..." is in opposite to the @Entity annotation. Your field clientId seems to be a foreign reference to one of your Client entities.

Usually such a 1:n relationship is modelled by JPA trough an entity reference, although the DB only has a Long ClientId as foreign key. The creation of the instance of the Client is done by JPA implementation (e.g. Hibernate) when you fetch a result set.

But you have to annotate the member by indicating the DB-Field which describes the relationship. E.g. (assuming one client can have more than one DebitAccount):

```
@ManyToOne(mappedBy="clientId")
Client client;
```

On the other hand, the @Entity implementations (the descendants of Client) must annotate how Hibernate can distiguish the two types, e.g. by a DB-Field ClientType. There are many possibilities to model this. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049510/how-do-i-express-a-polymorphic-association-in-jpa) may be a starting point.

Comment: This `mappedBe` just doesn't work. I don't know why, actually

Comment: You said `Client` is an interface in your code. You should make it an actual class that has the fields of your database table. That's how object-relational mapping works

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution of the problem. I just added `transient` before class name and variable name, like that:

```java
private transient Client clientId;
public Long getClientId() { return clientId.getId(); }
public void setClientId(Client clientId) { this.clientId = clientId; }
```

And, for example, using `getClientId` I just need to call method in interface.

Comment: This 'transient' is a java keyword and it says that this field is not serialized if you serialize the instance. There is also the JPA-Annotation @Transient which tells the JPA implementation that this field is not to be mapped to a DB field but maintained by your code.

Comment: In the context of JPA `transient` and `@Transient` have the same functionality. With both solutions the transient field is not persistent, meaning your `clientId` will not be filled with the value from your database table when reading entries from the database and if you save a entry to the database the `clientId` will not be set. I am not sure if that is something you actually want...